# Ant -- copying files and subdirectories from only one subdirectory on a tree

Tags: ant

I'd like to copy files and subdirectories using Ant from a single subdirectory without copying the rest of the directory structure and contents.  For example, I'd like to copy dir_3, its files (file_1 to file_n) and subdirectories (dir_4 and dir_5), but not dir_1 nor dir_2. Is there a pattern that I can use to do this?

```
temp
   \--dir_1
   \--dir_2
       |
       \--dir_3
           |
           \--dir_4
           \--dir_5
           \-- file_1
           |
           \--file_n
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<copy todir="${copy.dir}">
     <fileset dir="temp">
         <include name="**/dir3/**"/>
     </fileset>
</copy>
```

When you use the `include` directive, it will only include the files that match the pattern you give it. In this case, I'm copying only those files that have `/dir3/` somewhere in their full path name. This includes sub-directories under `dir3` and all files under `dir3`.

You can use the `exclude` directive to override the `include` directives:

```
<copy todir="${copy.dir}">
     <fileset dir="temp">
         <include name="**/dir3/**"/>
         <exclude name="**/dir3/*"/>
     </fileset>
</copy>
```

This will copy all sub-directories and files in those sub directories, but not the files under `dir3` itself. The `*` matches all files in the directory while `**` matches the all the files in the entire directory tree.

Notice this will create a directory `temp/dir2/dir3`. If I want `temp/dir3`, I have to set my fileset to the parent directory of `dir3`:

```
<copy todir="${copy.dir}">
     <fileset dir="temp/dir2">
         <include name="dir3/**"/>
     </fileset>
</copy>
```

Doing this:

```
<copy todir="${copy.dir}">
     <fileset dir="temp/dir2/dir3"/>
</copy>
```

Will create a directory `temp` with all the files directly under `dir3` directly under `temp`. There will also be a `temp/dir4` and `temp/dir5` directory containing all the files (and directory trees) under those directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
<copy todir="/some/path/foobar" verbose="true">
  <fileset dir="/some/path/temp/dir2" includes="**"/>
</copy>
```

just use a fileset starting from dir2 including all dirs and files below..
verbose = true to echo all the files copied
May be you need to use overwrite = true also if the dir that is specified by todir
attribute already exists, otherwise existing files won't be overwritten by copy task