# copy sub directories as well using Jenkins S3 plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I am using s3 plugin in Jenkins to copy my project from GIT to S3.

Its working fine; except that it copies only the top level files. It doesn't copy the subdirectories or the files with in the sub directory.

How can I achieve a *full* copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your OS where the Jenkins job is executed: [JENKINS issue 27576](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27576) seems to indicate it was an issue, but [PR 55](https://github.com/jenkinsci/s3-plugin/pull/55) also shows the right syntax to use for a recursive upload:

> We had the S3 plugin configured with the source parameter as `trunk/build/resources/**/*` on Windows builders.

So in your case, make sure your path to upload finishes with `/**/*` in order to consider *all* files.

Answer (score 0):

[Ant -- copying files and subdirectories from only one subdirectory on a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430192/ant-copying-files-and-subdirectories-from-only-one-subdirectory-on-a-tree)

This helped me a lot

if you only what to upload to s3 the whole folder use: `foldername/**/`

i used this to host a nuxt project in s3 with the dist generated folder.