# Copy explicit directory and files/subdirs

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Copy to Slave plugin for Jenkins, I want to copy some artifacts back the the master node workspace.  I was following the information in ([Ant -- copying files and subdirectories from only one subdirectory on a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430192/ant-copying-files-and-subdirectories-from-only-one-subdirectory-on-a-tree). The problem is that it's a Node application so a lot of nested directories and some with the same name, and by using the ant fileset nomenclature I am getting back ALL subdirectories on the slave back to my master node that match that pattern.

So, to give a more detailed instruction,

```
workspace
   \--dir_a
   \--dir_b
       |
       \--dir_c
           |
           \--dir_d
           \--dir_e
           \--  file_1
           \--  file_2
   \--dir_f
       |
       \--dir_b
       \--  file_3
```

You'll notice that dir_b is listed twice, directly in the workspace, but also again at workspace/dir_f/dir_b.  What I want is only the one specific directory, all it's files and its subdirs, recursively:

```
workspace/dir_b
```

So, if I use Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node, and specify:

```
**/dir_b/**
```

I get both:

```
workspace/dir_b/       and all it's files and subdirs
workspace/dir_f/dir_b  and all it's files and subdirs
```

So, how to write the fileset to only get the one specific subdir and its contents?

I also tried using

```
*/dir_b/**
```

But got nothing back.

And trying this seemed closer

```
dir_b/**
```

<s>but it only got me dir_b and it's files, not subdirectories or their files (though this didn't makes sense to me).</s>  Turns out this did work.  I had expected the subdirs/files to have a newer timestamp upon the re-run, but they didn't.  So I removed this dir/files and re-ran, and it recreated the subdir/files.

Help!?

Comment: What exactly is the problem now that the `dir_b/**` pattern is copying the files that you were targeting? You want them to have a new modified date?

Comment: @CAustin - because some of the files in dir_c were updated I had expected dir_c (under dir_b) to have a new timestamp upon rerun but it didn't....always...it was unclear why sometimes it would and other times it wouldn't so was hard to tell if my new run had succeeded or simply had data left over from the prior run.  I've read up on this, but still the behavior didn't seem to exactly follow the rules so kind of puzzled on that part even though I did get it to work.